# How do I use UI.registerHelper in Meteor 0.8.0?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

In 0.7.2, I could have something like this

```
<span>{{color 'blue'}}</span>

Handlebars.registerHelper('color', function (parameter) {
   return Session.equals('color', parameter) ? 'blue' : 'red';
});
```

and it would work perfectly fine. What is the equivalent in the 0.8.0 release? I know they replaced Handlebars.registerHelper with UI.registerHelper, but this

```
UI.registerHelper('color', function (parameter) {
    return Session.equals('color', parameter) ? 'blue' : 'red';
});
```

still returns this error

```
Exception in Meteor UI: Error: Can't call non-function: [object Object]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was all because one of my registerHelpers was the word 'parent'. Using that threw an error so it made it seem like all of my helpers were messed up. I'm guessing that it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this & it works (exactly as I use it). Do you use iron-router? This might do too.

```
UI.registerHelper('routeActive', function(routeName) {
var route = Router.current();

    if(route && route.route && route.route.name == routeName) return 'active';
});
```

Then you can use the name of your template/route in `routeName`

I'm a bit unsure why you're getting that error are you sure its from the Handlebars expression.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure it's from the Handlebars expression and I'm using iron-router but this problem doesn't have anything to do with routing. I was using this helper to simply return text within my html.

Comment: Did you try using the above instead? Does it work for you? It does the same thing ( I think? )

Comment: Sorry im a bit confused is the snippet of code that you've provided the same one causing you the issues? If not could you provide the one that is?

Comment: Okay I changed the code to use 'colors' instead of 'activePath' to make it more clear that his has nothing to do with routing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass the parameter with a name:

```
<span>{{activePath path='home'}}</span>

UI.registerHelper('activePath', function() {
  return Session.equals('activePath', this.path) ? 'active' : '';
});
```

Comment: I'm using `{{routeActive 'home'}}` in my one (w 0.8.0), is it supposed to be done this new way?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is mandatory – I'm still looking around 0.8.0 – but this fixed some of my problems, and I recall reading about this change in docs, although I cannot find the place at this moment. If it works for you, then perhaps you can use the old syntax in some circumstances.

Comment: This didn't work either. I tried `{{activePath path=home}}` as well too but that didn't work, same error.